# VSCode - how can I add highlighting to the line with the cursor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I add highlighting to the line with the cursor?

Like this official tutorial screenshot - [link](http://prntscr.com/j0ahjx).
In my case, it looks like this - [link](http://prntscr.com/j0ajkt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This color is provided by themes using `editor.lineHighlightBackground`.

You can override this by adding `workbench.colorCustomizations` in your user settings

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#ff00ff"
}
```

[image]